# how to solve " You have an error in your SQL syntax." error meassage

Tags: php, sql

here is my code

```
$sql14 = ("SELECT count(`MarksID`) AS all FROM tbl_course_marks_result WHERE tbl_course_marks_result.`StudentID` = '$k' AND tbl_course_marks_result.`CourseID`='$courseID' AND tbl_course_marks_result.`SessionID`='$sessionID' AND tbl_course_marks_result.`TermID`='$termID' ");
    $result14 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql14);
if($result14 === FALSE) { 
    die(mysqli_error($connect));
}
```

here showing this error message "  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'all FROM tbl_course_marks_result WHERE tbl_course_marks_result.`StudentID` = '17' at line 1" How to solve this???

Comment: all is a reserved keyword.Try a different alias name instead of all.

Comment: @Kapil this is the answer I was going to post. Please post it as answer so it can be properly accepted.

Comment: Added to answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is a reserved keyword.Use a different alias name like below

```
 $sql14 = ("SELECT count(`MarksID`) AS all_marksid FROM tbl_course_marks_result     WHERE tbl_course_marks_result.`StudentID` = '$k' AND  tbl_course_marks_result.`CourseID`='$courseID' AND tbl_course_marks_result.`SessionID`='$sessionID' AND tbl_course_marks_result.`TermID`='$termID' ");
$result14 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql14);
 if($result14 === FALSE) { 
die(mysqli_error($connect));
}
```

Comment: You can also write `as \`all\`` instead of `as all`.

Comment: Thank you :) It's my mistake

Comment: @Tashfi Please accept this as answer,if it helped you.